# Segmented controls memory usage

Tags: ios, memory-management, segue, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to make my own version of a container view with a custom segue and a tool bar that could switch between a UICollectionViewController and a UITableViewController.

After a few tries I got it working and it seems to be behaving like it should but then it came to my attention that I wasn't considering the proper clean up of my views, children VCs, etc.

I tried really hard to follow the logic behind the examples of the tutorials I've followed (Ray Wenderlich's iOS by Tutorials 5 and 6) but I still think I'm not freeing the memory as I should using the removeFromParentViewController and removeFromSuperview messages.

To better understand how my code works here's a screenshot and also a short video:

**The app:**

[image]

**Memory usage when switching VCs:**

[image]

**The video that shows it:**

[YouTube link](http://youtu.be/Hmgp01Q6mFA)

Here's the section of code where I handle the views hierarchy and clean up (overridden perform: method for the custom segue):

```
- (void) perform
{
    // Set source and destination view controllers
    FirstViewController *sourceViewController = (FirstViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    // Handle child and parent view controller designation (the view controller’s view is added to the window hierarchy)
    destinationViewController.view.frame = sourceViewController.containerView.bounds;

    [sourceViewController addChildViewController:destinationViewController];

    [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    [sourceViewController.containerView addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

    [destinationViewController didMoveToParentViewController:sourceViewController];

    // Remove actual destinationViewController from the container every time there's a transition (segue)
    [destinationViewController removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

I'm also logging the number of children on the parent VC (the tab bar First VC):

```
NSLog(@"Amount of Children: %d", [self.childViewControllers count]);
```

and I'm checking that the count doesn't go up (like it does when I neglect to use removeFromParentViewController):

[image]

Maybe I'm not entirely getting the concepts but since the memory goes up with each switch I'm getting the impression that my clean up is not right or at least that it's missing something.

Are you able to see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

When profiling choose "leaks" to check for memory leaks. Now you're checking for memory allocations and it's normal that memory usage can grow up between view switching because of initialization of new objects. Things that you should avoid is constant memory growth after continuous switching between views

Comment: Hi Roma, that's a good thing to know but leaks is also right there on the screenshot.  I'm monitoring both in this case just because the instruments "Leak" selection put both indicators there. Thanks!

Comment: Leaks mode gives you a bit more info about them. I'm not sure but in "leaks" mode you can double click red leak line and it will show you the "problem part". Maybe you can do the same in allocations mode.